# Push Notification Delegates not getting called

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I am implementing push notification for a client. I have followed all the steps of push notifications setup on device (including certificate generation and everything).

I have used following links as reference:

- [Apple Push Notification Services Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12)
- [Programming Apple Push Notification Services](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/programming-apple-push-notification-services?dm_switcher=true)

I call this function in app delegates `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
```

After setup, i run the app i get the Blue Push notification warning dialogue but after I press Ok the delegates are not called.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError*)error
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
```

None of these delegates are called ever. I am stuck here as i cannot proceed further as none of the delegates is called.

If any of you has faced a similar issue i would be very very thankful if you can help me out here.

Comment: `didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError` should be called if something is wrong. Are testing it on Simulator or device? Also if you do 'Jump to Definition' on didFail delegate does it bring you to UIApplication.h header file? (just making sure there is no typos or anything obvious like this)

Comment: Did you enable push notifications when creating the app ID through your developer account?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this before, you need to just add [application registerForRemoteNotifications]; to your code, where application is the instance of UIApplication inside the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method of the app delegate. Make sure you add this once you have set up your UINotificationType, and UIUserNotificationSettings